# Loop an algorithm process across points using PyQGIS with variable attribute from points layer

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I have a simple working PyQGIS script in the python console which runs the native function: *Service Area from Layer*, which works when I define the TRAVEL_COST as an integer, i.e *250*.

However, I want the TRAVEL_COST variable for each START_POINT to read from a field called "Value" from the points layer, at the moment it runs all the way through, but the resulting service areas lines have 0 length, I think this *might* be because the *layer* isn't specified for the "value" entry, but I'm not sure how to do that.

I have checked the QgsProperty.fromExpression documentation but I can't see how to assign a layer, perhaps that's not the real issue.

The points layer attribute table in simple terms is:

```
| fid      | Value          |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1        | 1000           |
| 2        | 2000           |
```

My non-working code is here:

```
lyr1 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Points')[0]
lyr2 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Roads')[0]

input1 = lyr1
input2 = lyr2

output = 'memory:Your output'

result = processing.run("native:serviceareafromlayer",
    {
    'INPUT':input2,
    'START_POINTS':input1,
    'TRAVEL_COST':QgsProperty.fromExpression('"Value"'), # Seems to be returning 0 values, rather than 1000, 2000 etc.
    'OUTPUT_LINES':output
    }
    )

print(result)

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(result['OUTPUT_LINES'])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using Service area from point. Iterate over each point, fetch its coordinates and distance, append all results to a list and merge:

```
starts = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("start_points")[0]
fieldname = "distance" #Fieldname where you've got the distances 
lines = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("roads")[0]

result_lines = []
for feature in starts.getFeatures(): #For each point
    dist = feature[fieldname] #Fetch the distance value from the field
    print(dist)
    pnt = feature.geometry().asPoint()

    #Service area from point is expecting a string as input with x,y and crs, like this: '756563.2183999997,7093349.537300002 [EPSG:3006]'
    start_point = f"{pnt.x()},{pnt.y()} [{starts.crs().authid()}]" #Create it
    
    result = processing.run("native:serviceareafrompoint", {'INPUT':lines,
    'STRATEGY':0,'DIRECTION_FIELD':'','VALUE_FORWARD':'','VALUE_BACKWARD':'',
    'VALUE_BOTH':'','DEFAULT_DIRECTION':2,'SPEED_FIELD':'',
    'DEFAULT_SPEED':50,'TOLERANCE':0,'START_POINT':start_point,
    'TRAVEL_COST2':dist,'INCLUDE_BOUNDS':False,
    'OUTPUT_LINES':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})["OUTPUT_LINES"]
    result.setName(f"distance_{dist}")
    result_lines.append(result)

processing.runAndLoadResults("native:mergevectorlayers", {'LAYERS':result_lines,
    'CRS':None,'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})

print("Done")
```

[image]